# I can't access hidden .onion sites on my tor browser

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, onion-services, help

My tor browser will connect just fine to some .onion sites, such as duckduckgo http://3g2upl4pq6kufc4m.onion/, but if I try to connect to a hidden .onion site, say http://sheep5u64fi457aw.onion/, it says it is unable to connect.  I have tried this on numerous hidden sites and received the same error.  Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I added another answer on the linked question.  Go there and see if it helps.